# Axios 'mode' does not exist in type 'AxiosRequestConfig'

Tags: typescript, axios, cors

Describe the bug

I am trying to make a request which requires the mode to be set to `no-cors`.  However, I am unable to pass `mode` into the Axios config. I receive the TypeScript error  `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'mode' does not exist in type 'AxiosRequestConfig'`

Ultimately, I need to be able to make a request where `sec-fetch-mode: no-cors` is present.

```
const client: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: apiBaseUrl,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  },
  adapter: cache.adapter,
});
```

Whether it's through `mode` or another property, I am needing a way to make this request.

To Reproduce

```js
const mediaUrl: string = await client
  .get(paths.moment.media.getMediaUrl({ mediaId: media.id }), {
    mode: 'no-cors'
  })
.then(({ data }: { data: string }): string => data);
```

Expected behavior

To be able to set `mode` to `no-cors` for a specific request.

Environment

- Axios 0.20.0
- TypeScript 4.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mode` is not supported for configuring axios requests.

`mode` is available on [Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode), but not on [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).
If XMLHttpRequest is available, it is used by axios by default: ([defaults.js](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/defaults.js#L16))

```
function getDefaultAdapter() {
  var adapter;
  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') {
    // For browsers use XHR adapter
    adapter = require('./adapters/xhr');
  } else if (typeof process !== 'undefined' && Object.prototype.toString.call(process) === '[object process]') {
    // For node use HTTP adapter
    adapter = require('./adapters/http');
  }
  return adapter;
}
```

See: [similar problem in axios repo](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1358#issuecomment-364789526)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `sec-fetch-mode: no-cors` header in the request?

```
const mediaUrl: string = await client
  .get(paths.moment.media.getMediaUrl({ mediaId: media.id }), {
    headers: {
      'sec-fetch-mode': 'no-cors',
    }
  })
.then(({ data }: { data: string }): string => data);
```

Comment: Yeah, I had tried that before, but no luck with it.